# Camunda - Not able to access the resource of one tenant from other tenant

Tags: camunda

I have a business requirement where I need a multi-tenant camunda application. In this application few tenants or few users from that tenant will be to access some resources like process instance of other tenants/users.
To check how we can achieve this I created a camunda + springBoot app, added 2 tenants and 2 processes for each tenant. Then through admin authorization I tried to give read access of process instance from tenant1 to tenant2. After logging in as a tenant2 user I can's see the process instance of belonging to tenant1.

- I would like to know is this requirement possible to achieve in camunda?
- If it is, what extra steps do I need to take.

I am new to camunda, I will really appriciate if any one could help me out.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Tenants are fully separated. That includes authorizations. You could use an SSO mechanism to allow the same external user credentials to get access to both environments. This would mean technically two different users with different authorizations per tenant.